# What HTML element does jQuery $(document) correspond to?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I thought is was the `<HTML>` tag but that doesn't seem to be correct. Am I missing something?

If so, is there any reason I shouldn't give the `<HTML>/$(document)` an `id` or other attributes which I could manipulate using jQuery/Javascript?

Comment: The second part of your question isn't clear, you can access the document with `$(document)` and the HTML root with `$('html')` - what other type of ID do you want to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `document` variable refers to a memory object in JavaScript that does not correspond to anything in the HTML or the DOM tree.  It is, instead, the object that *contains* the DOM tree.  It is, in turn, contained by the Window object, which is the global object in browser-based Javascript.

The `<html>` element, on the other hand, is part of the DOM tree.  So you can get it the same way you can get any other element, with *e.g.* `document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0]`.  But since it's the *root* of the DOM tree, that's kind of silly; you can access it directly as `document.documentElement`.  That works for the root of any DOM document, including XML (perhaps returned by an Ajax call).  In the usual case of an HTML document, you would probably just use `document.html`.  Or the jQuery equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

The `document` is a browser object that is the entry point for HTML content, accessing the URL, and other functionality. It contains the DOM tree, which in turn contains your HTML elements.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document

Comment: so I guess I could just perform all the operations on the <HTML> tag? I'm trying to do endless scrolling.

Comment: I have traditionally used `$(window).scrollTop()` and then checked the value against another element's `$(element).offset().top` value - http://api.jquery.com/scrollTop/